# Word Add-in problems when grab the text from Word

Tags: office-js, word-addins

I'am writing an Add-In for Word.
I want to grab the Text in word and convert the text to Html.
I used the example from the official documentation.
https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body

Basicly it works, but there is a problem I can't solve.
Everytime I grab the text from Word the program freezes for a second. (time depends on the legth of the document)
This hiccup makes Word unusable. 
I grab the Text in periodic intervals to make some analyzes.
I need a way to get the text and convert it to Html in the background without freezes.

```
// Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
return Word.run(function (context)
{
    var body = context.document.body;
    var content = body.getHtml();

    // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
    // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
    return context.sync().then(function () {
        console.log(content.value);
        return content.value;
    });
});
```

Comment: I have similar problems with word freezing when the addin is interacting with word. In my case writing to the document. 
Are you working with really large documents? 
Are you using customXml (reading and/or writing) in any way?

Comment: Tested only with 1000 Words. Then the freeze is around a second. 10 Words produces a freeze for a few milliseconds. No customXML, no writing. Just read the text from the Word body.

Comment: all the times that I trying get the HTML, the code is coming is a half content. Why?